# ¿Cómo puedo encontrar un registro dentro de otra tabla?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas vengo a este sitio web el cual ocupo ayuda para inicializar la búsqueda de un registro dentro de otra tabla en MYSQL que pudiese hacer lo siguiente:

Selecciono el registro deseado, si este registro se encuentra en la otra tabla que me mande un mensaje que diga "Si existe el usuario", en caso de que no exista que me mande un mensaje "no existe el usuario"...

Tengo la idea pero no sabría como implementarlo, si algunos me podrían ayudar en la ejecución de esta consulta ya que es la que me importa y no sé qué tipo de funciones de MYSQL utilizar para poder realizar la consulta. "Gracias por su atención".
[image: Descripcion de los campos de mis tablas]

Comment: Hola Edir. No entiendo cuando dices "Selecciono el registro deseado". Que son esos registros? Empleados? Jornadas? Porqué si seleccionas el registro, está claro que existe. Si seleccionar empleados, quieres saber si ese empleado tiene jornadas? La pregunta no queda muy claro lo que pides...

Comment: Como no queda claro que es lo que quieres exactamente y sacando una conclusión rápida, te dejo una sentencia que te devolvería el número de jornadas para un empleado en concreto `SELECT count(*) AS NumeroJornadas FROM jornadas JOIN empleados ON empleados.id = jornadas.id_empleado WHERE jornadas.id_empleado = IDaBuscar GROUP BY jornadas.id_empleado`. De todas formas estaría bien que copiaras el código que has probado o las pruebas que hayas hecho...

Comment: @FerranMuñoz gracias por responder mi publicación.. bueno lo que quiero realizar es lo siguiente: si tengo un empleado llamado "juan" quiero saber si en mi tabla jornadas existe un registro con este nombre, en caso "de que exista" me mande un mensaje "existe este nombre" en caso "de que no existe" me mande "no hay ninguno con este nombre". no se si me hago entender lo que quiero, aunque ni se si lo estoy comentando adecuadamente xD una disculpa por mi escritura y gracias por su atención.